# Need some help with my first LaTeX drawing…

Tags: align

I have two simple equations I need to draw out with LaTeX. I suspect these are simple, and it would be a big help to get me started on the rest of my document. Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction, particularly how to handle the variable-height braces wrapping the equations?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: TikZ (a graph drawing package) treats curly brace as line segment: that is, you may *draw* a curly brace from, say, point (0,1) to point (0,3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\ 1+4+4 &= 9 \\
&\left.\begin{aligned}
1+1+3\\ 1+2+2\\ 1+3+1
\end{aligned} \right\} &= 5
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
1 + 4+4 \hphantom{\Bigg\} } & = 9\\
\left.
\begin{aligned}
1+1+3\\
1+2+2\\
1+3+1
\end{aligned}\right\} & =5
\end{aligned}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```